# Uploading a File to Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, file-upload, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

How to upload a file via Jenkins pipleine input paramter?
I have defined an input parameter as below
[image]

Now that I have checked a few other codes and blogs am not sure what to provide for File Location.

Also, how to access that file in my script? With the above configuration (in image), I can access the file name using ${Asset}

The requirement is to upload a file via the browser and send that file in cUrl request.

Comment: Are you on a Freestyle project or a Declarative Pipeline?

Comment: declarative pipeline

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the default File Parameter use the [File Parameters plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/file-parameters/). Here is an example.

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  parameters {
    base64File 'yamlFile'
  }
  stages {
    stage('Example') {
      steps {
        withFileParameter('yamlFile') {
          def configVal = readYaml file: yamlFile
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tested it with zip file and it seems to upload the file, can see stashed file and the path. How to send this file as form data in a cUrl request?

Comment: prepared a cUrl and ran it, can see it as - -F "asset= @"C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\publish-api@tmp\Asset"" - but not the actual file name like lib.zip. "Asset " is the field name